# Create and edit the resource group created for snapshots in with bicep

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-bicep

I am trying to create a backup policy, and specify name the resource group that is created by the backup policy. This is possible with Powershell according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-automation#creating-azure-backup-resource-group-during-snapshot-retention)

```
$bkpPol = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -name "DefaultPolicyForVMs"
$bkpPol.AzureBackupRGName="Contosto_"
$bkpPol.AzureBackupRGNameSuffix="ForVMs"
Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -policy $bkpPol
```

I want to do this in bicep. But i can't find how i can specify this in the properties of the backup-policy.
Is this possible? If now: is it maybe possible with a powershell deployment script?
Thanks!

Comment: @VenkatV Hmm, I think I found the answer. It is possible to do in this way:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#protectionpolicy-objects

Comment: The document you have provided is related to the different types of protection policy objects. What is your ask? Can you brief about it. @ahmedmobarak

Answer (score 0):

After a workaround on your requirement, I found that specifying a resource group name under recovery vault back up policy is not exactly possible with bicep.

And resource creation is usually managed separately from the backup policy itself. While creating a backup policy, a `Recovery Services Vault` is associated with it by default, and the vault is already linked to a specific resource group.

It means that the resource group for the vault is determined during the creation of the vault, but not the backup policy. So, it is not needed in bicep to mention or specify a resource group under backup policy separately. If still your requirement is to specify, you can use `parent` property or `dependsOn` block available in bicep.

I have also referred the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#protectionpolicy-objects) you have given. I tried to deploy the code with the same reference `properties` for a `backup` policy as shown below and the deployment was succeeded.

```bash
param vmname string = 'newvmj'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource rVirtualMachine 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2023-09-01' existing = {
  name: vmname
}
resource rRecoveryServiceVault 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults@2023-08-01' = {
  name: 'latestjahv'
  location: location
  properties: {
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard'
  }
  dependsOn: [
    rVirtualMachine
  ]
}
resource rRecoveryServiceVaultBackupPolicy 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies@2023-08-01' = {
  name: 'backupjahpol'
  parent: rRecoveryServiceVault
  properties: {
    backupManagementType: 'AzureIaasVM'
    instantRpRetentionRangeInDays: 5
    timeZone: 'Eastern Standard Time'
    protectedItemsCount: 0
    schedulePolicy: {
      schedulePolicyType: 'SimpleSchedulePolicy'
      scheduleRunFrequency: 'Weekly'
      scheduleRunDays: [
        'Sunday'
      ]
      scheduleRunTimes: [
        '2024-02-13T23:00:00Z'
      ]
      scheduleWeeklyFrequency: 0
    }
    retentionPolicy: {
      retentionPolicyType: 'LongTermRetentionPolicy'
      weeklySchedule: {
        daysOfTheWeek: [
          'Sunday'
        ]
        retentionTimes: [
          '2024-02-13T23:00:00Z'
        ]
        retentionDuration: {
          count: 12
          durationType: 'Weeks'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

*Reference:* [Document](https://www.bluefini.com/azure-bicep-how-to-setup-recovery-services-vault-to-backup-virtual-machine/#:%7E:text=Azure%20Bicep%20%E2%80%93%20How%20to%20Setup%20Recovery%20Services,6%20Step%206:%20Lets%20deploy%20the%20resource%20)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Indeed, I wasn't clear initially. My question was originally about the resource group automatically created by the snapshot retention policy. After posing the question, I found out that it is documented as follows:

`backupManagementType: 'AzureIaasVM'
instantRPDetails: {
  azureBackupRGNamePrefix: 'string' // This is what I meant to refer to
  azureBackupRGNameSuffix: 'string'  `

Comment: Yes, as you said it could be clearer but I understood your query and deployed the same properties if you can check. @ahmedmobarak